# Powershell script block with arguments as string

Tags: powershell

I if a strings, which contains a powershell script block:

```or-tag-here
$scriptBlock = 'Param (
    [string]$param1,
    [string]$param2,
    [switch]$param3
)
Write-Output ('param1: {0}' -f $param1)
Write-Output ('param2: {0}' -f $param2)
Write-Output ('param3: {0}' -f $param3)'
```

Inside a second string I have the arguments for the script block.

```or-tag-here
$arguments = '-param1 "param1Value" -param2 "param2Value" -param3'
```

My question is how can I invoke the script block with the aruments string?

Comment: Why do you have the arguments in a single string? How did you obtain them in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$scriptblock` string assignment is syntactically invalid, use a here-string to avoid having to escape the `'`s:

```
$scriptBlock = @'
Param (
    [string]$param1,
    [string]$param2,
    [switch]$param3
)
Write-Output ('param1: {0}' -f $param1)
Write-Output ('param2: {0}' -f $param2)
Write-Output ('param3: {0}' -f $param3)
'@
```

You could define a function with the contents of the `$scriptblock` string:

```
$functionName = "__command$(Get-Random)"
New-Item -Path function:\ -Name $functionName -Value $scriptBlock
```

Then invoke it using `Invoke-Expression`:

```
$result = Invoke-Expression "$functionName $arguments"
```

And clean up:

```
Remove-Item function:\$functionName
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.